# How to use Nodejs package in Reactjs Application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I want to use this library in my react project

https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-convert

But I couldn't find this package for Reactjs Application. Please provide a solution to use this package in my reactjs application without any issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use this package right away in your application. just npm install it and require/import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its npm package, you can use it in your React application as is.

```
npm install color-convert

# or
yarn add color-convert
```

```
import convert from 'color-convert';

const App = () => {
  const [hsl,setHsl] = useState(convert.rgb.hsl(140, 200, 100));
  return <>...</>
}
```